# What is an alternative to populating a DropDownList with a ViewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have read that ViewBags are bad  and should be avoided if at all possible, and yet every training piece I have seen  (including the [MVC 5 tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) and many SO answers) shows the style shown below to populate a DropDownList in the View.

If it's one or two parameters, it's not noticeable, but a customer requested something very specific: a monster-sized table with 20 separate independent parameters used to filter the database query.  The example I have shown you is highly trimmed down. Just imagine that there are far more parameters, and can imagine how the Index Action would become very fat and not-simple.

I can use `#region` blocks to collapse sections of the Action, which can help with organization and readability, but I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Here lies the big question: are there any alternatives to the use of ViewBags to populate DropDownLists from the Controller?

**Excerpt from the Index Action in the Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(string campus = "CRA", string fy = "FY16", int? ageYr)
{                       
    // Used to populate the DropDownLists in the HTML.BeginForm() block.
    ViewBag.CampusList = new SelectList(new List<string> { "CRA", "DRA", "MRA", "PRA" }, campus);
    ViewBag.FyList = new SelectList(new List<string> { "FY12", "FY13", "FY14", "FY15", "FY16" }, fy);                        

    // Optional Filter
    List<int?> ages = query.Select(m => (int?)m.AgeYrAtEndOfSy).Distinct().OrderBy(m => m).ToList();
    ages.Insert(0, null);
    ViewBag.AgeYrList = new SelectList(ages, ageYr);

    IEnumerable<StudentSummaryLayer0> query = db.StudentSummaryLayer0
        .Where(m => m.Campus == campus).Where(m => m.FY == fy);

    if (ageYr != null) query = query.Where(m => m.AgeYrAtEndOfSy == ageYr);            

    query = query.OrderBy(m => m.StudentName);

    return View(query.ToList());
}
```

**Excerpt from the Index View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<RoseDashboardFY16.Models.StudentSummaryLayer0>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "StudentSummaryLayer0", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Filter results</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>
                Required Filters: <br />
                <strong>Campus</strong>: @Html.DropDownList("campus", (SelectList)ViewBag.CampusList)
                <strong>FY</strong>: @Html.DropDownList("fy", (SelectList)ViewBag.FyList)
            </p>

            @*Imagine many more parameters.*@
            <p style="line-height:2.0">
                Optional Attribute Filters: <br />                
                <span class="KeepTogether">
                    <strong>Age (Yr)</strong>: @Html.DropDownList("ageYr", (SelectList)ViewBag.AgeYrList)
                </span>
            </p>

            <div><input type="submit" value="Search" /><input type="reset" value="Reset"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: [How do I create a view model for a populated drop down list in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882700/how-do-i-create-a-view-model-for-a-populated-drop-down-list-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: As Shyju's link suggests, start with a View Model.

Comment: Yep. I'm looking into it now. I'm starting off simple but haven't gotten my Hello World to work yet.

Comment: Herein lies another gap in the instructional knowledge base. I've looked for "MVC ViewModel Tutorial" and found that "ViewModel" was completely absent from the lesson "http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3".  The search continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, the preferred method is to use a view model. The big problem with `ViewBag` and why its use is discouraged is that it's dynamic. You lose type-safety and are forced to do manual casting, which can lead to bugs. Additionally, since the casting is done in the view, you get *runtime* bugs, which are like little time-bombs in your code. Ideally, you want errors at compile-time so you can fix them before you deploy. A view model allows you to stay strongly-typed and will break at compile-time if it's going to break at all.

As far as keeping your actions clean, construction of your select lists should be handled either in your view model or in a private/protected method on your controller (if it requires database-access). This way you can easily reuse the same construction elsewhere it may be need. For instance, with GET and POST versions of an action:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    ...

    PopulateSelectLists(model);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(FooViewModel model)
{
    ...

    PopulateSelectLists(model);
    return View(model);
}

private void PopulateSelectLists(FooViewModel model)
{
    // set select list properties
}
```

Additionally, you want to avoid newing up `SelectList` instances. All Razor needs is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. It will automatically create the `SelectList` instance and set the appropriate item's `Selected` property based on the model's state.

Comment: I think you are pointing me in the right direction. It is apparent I need to learn about ViewModels. In my case, the "Model" is the database table which is populated by the linq query. The additional IEnumerables are distinct from the linq query, and so I need to figure out how to do this. I even purchased the John Galloway book on MVC 5 and he says that I shouldn't use the example posted, and then he goes ahead and does just that. +1 for now, but still working on a workable answer.

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer because it suggests the a sound approach. Still working on making it happen, however.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to populate drop down lists. I never use `view bags`. Below is code on how I normally populate my drop down lists.

In my example I am going to populate a drop down list containing a list of statuses. When my `view` contains a list of items and nothing else then I am ok to pass through a list to the view, and not a `view model`. If there is more data that needs to be passed to the view then I will make use of a view model. In this example I made use of a view model because it needs to contain a list of statuses and the selected status id:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
     public int StatusId { get; set; }

     public List<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `domain model` that will contain each status data:

```
public class Status
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller's action method I would populate the list of statuses. Normally from a database call, but in this example I am hard coding my list:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     TestViewModel model = new TestViewModel();

     model.Statuses = new List<Status>();
     model.Statuses.Add(new Status { Id = 1, Name = "Status 1" });
     model.Statuses.Add(new Status { Id = 2, Name = "Status 2" });
     model.Statuses.Add(new Status { Id = 3, Name = "Status 3" });

     return View(model);
}
```

After the list has been populated I pass the view model to the view. The view accepts this view model and creates the drop down list:

```
@model WebApplication_Test.Models.TestViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     <div>
          @Html.DropDownListFor(
               m => m.StatusId,
               new SelectList(Model.Statuses, "Id", "Name", Model.StatusId),
               "-- Select --"
          )
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StatusId)
     </div>
     <div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </div>
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe still not getting it, but it looks to me as if the model is solely the dropdown list. I need the dropdownlist to be distinct from the domain model that is rendered in the table.