# ASP.NET MVC Retrieve Data from Database to DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Core, Entity Framework Core and SQL Server. I have the following Models and Controllers listed below. Everything works fine, I'm able to retrieve the data from my Database to my DropDownList Controls using  fine.

What I would like to know if someone could assist me with is there a better way to retrieve the data in the "public IActionResult Create()" that I have now within the EmployeeController?

I would like if possible but not sure how to, create 2 Methods called public IActionResult DeptData() and IActionResult BldgData() to retrieve the data to those Methods and then pass the returned data to the public IActionResult Create() Method of the EmployeeController rather than how I have it now.

**Employee Model:**

```
    public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EmpFirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EmpLastName { get; set; }

    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public int BldgId { get; set; }
    public Building Building { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeeController:**

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private DataEntryContext _context;

    public EmployeeController(DataEntryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Employees.ToList());
    }

    public string RetrieveDept()
    {
        var getDeptTitle = _context.Departments.ToList();
        SelectList Deptlist = new SelectList(getDeptTitle, "DeptId", "DeptTitle");
        ViewBag.DeptListName = Deptlist;

        return View(Create);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var getDeptTitle = _context.Departments.ToList();
        SelectList Deptlist = new SelectList(getDeptTitle, "DeptId", "DeptTitle");
        ViewBag.DeptListName = Deptlist;

        var getBldgTitle = _context.Buildings.ToList();
        SelectList Bldglist = new SelectList(getBldgTitle, "BldgId", "BldgName");
        ViewBag.BldgListName = Bldglist;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Employees.Add(employee);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(employee);
    }
}
```

**Employee Create View:**

```
<form asp-controller="employee" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="EmpFirstName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="EmpFirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpFirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="EmpLastName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="EmpLastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpLastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DeptId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">      
            <select asp-for="DeptId" asp-items="@ViewBag.DeptListName" class="form-control"></select>  
            <span asp-validation-for="DeptId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BldgId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="BldgId" asp-items="@ViewBag.BldgListName" class="form-control"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="BldgId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: both of the dropdowns could be partial views. You just need to pass the lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to wrap the code to get the items needed for the dropdown to a separate method which can be called from other action methods.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.DeptListName = GetDepartments();
    // Do the same for your other dropdown also
    return View();
 }
 private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDepartments()
 {
      return context.Departments
                    .Select(s=> new SelectListItem { 
                                                     Value=s.DeptId.ToString(),
                                                     Text=s.DeptTitle })
                    .ToList();
 }
```

I personally prefer to avoid ViewBag and ViewData and use a strongly typed view model to pass these data to the view. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-mvc-6) is a post explaining how to do it if you are interested.

Comment: I like the simplicity with what you supplied above, but you mention to avoid using ViewBag and ViewData and use a strongly typed view instead. I looked at the article that you posted and somewhat confused by it.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882700/how-do-i-create-a-view-model-for-a-populated-drop-down-list-in-asp-net-mvc-3/9882809#9882809

Comment: I included your code above and it works fine as well. Is this better than what I was initially doing, if so why?

Also, how can I add a default value such as "Please select" to the DropDownList?

Comment: You can add an option inside your select tag with text "Please select"

Comment: Can you please explain to me the difference with what you provided that worked compared to what I did since they both use ViewBag? Is using ViewBag a bad idea? Does ViewBag have a hit on performance or causes security issues?

Comment: Maintainability issue :)

Comment: Ok, when you say maintainability issue, what needs to be maintained when using ViewBag or ViewData?

Comment: I like strong  typing than dynamic.

Comment: Ok, some problems with ViewBag: 1) you don't know what does ViewBag contain (no autocomplete, no types for members, etc...). 2) You cannot test views, because you need to provide ViewBag data. 3) Some other controller from the pipeline can override the ViewBag value. 4) The view itself does not say it needs specific type of param, so you cannot render it from another controller unless you learn the view internals. 5) Dynamic binding is much slower. 6) No compile-time errors (absence of a ViewBag key will occur only runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using partial views. Each of them with the relevant dropdowns.

First of all, I do not recommend using ViewBag, but strongly-typed views. So your master view will need to accept `MasterCreateViewModel` and you need to create one that has both `Buildings` and `Departments`

```
class MasterCreateViewModel
{
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public List<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
}
```

And your Master Create should return the view with this ViewModel.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var getDeptTitle = _context.Departments.ToList();
    var getBldgTitle = _context.Buildings.ToList();
    var viewModel = new MasterCreateViewModel()
                     {
                             Departments = getDeptTitle,
                             Buildings = getBldgTitle 
                     }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Then you need two actions that return partial views with the relevant dropdowns. E.g.

```
public IActionResult CreateDepartmentsPartial(List<Department> departments)
{
    return PartialView("CreateDepartmentsPartial", departments);
}
```

And, the partial view as well:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="DeptId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">      
        <select asp-for="DeptId" asp-items="@Model" class="form-control"></select>  
        <span asp-validation-for="DeptId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to Invoke the partial view with the relevant model:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="EmpLastName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="EmpLastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpLastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
@Html.RenderPartial("CreateDepartmentsPartial", Model.Departments)
```

P.S.: ASP.NET Core has also asynchronous partial rendering.

Comment: Seems like a lot to just retrieve data from DB to DropDownList :( I'm coming from WebForms and I use to create a Method that called the data then bound that to a DropDownList. Can that be done with MVC?

Comment: Just a call a method that can bind it to `ViewBag` if you want, but I do not appreciate that approach. My explanation is bit longer, but much maintainable.

Comment: I tried to implement what you supplied but was unable to get it to work, must be something wrong that I'm doing on my end. Is there a performance or security gain from your approach compared to using a ViewBag or ViewData?

Comment: The gain is maintanance, but there is performance one as well, becuse executing `ViewBag.SomeThing` invokes runtime dynamic features in C# which are slower

Comment: Ok, is there another way to handle this without using ViewBag that may just as simple as creating a function/method if you will that calls the data and then passes that data to a view or have the view from another method call that function/method?

Comment: It's either ViewBag/Data or a model bound to the view. There is not other way known to me.

Comment: Ok, I may try your approach again. Please be patient as I'm learning the in's and out's of MVC. I'm used to WebForms and having trouble wrapping my head around the MVC approach :)

Comment: Ok, so I need to right click on Models and create a new class.cs file called class MasterCreateViewModel with the information you supplied for this class?

Comment: The Master Create that you mentioned, I have 2 Create Methods for the EmployeeController. Which one do I need to add that code to?

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly, I need to create a new Model called MasterCreateViewModel inside of my Models folder. Then I need to open my EmployeeController and add the code for public IActionResult Create() along with adding the code for public IActionResult CreateDepartmentsPartial(List<Department> departments) all in my EmployeeController?

Comment: Do I just use the same Create View that I have now or do I need to create a special PartialView?