# how to specify Default value for dropdown i have populated from database using Viewbag in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity-framework-4

heloo guys i have populated dropdownlist from database in mvc using Viewbag object now i want to specify default value for it like Select Supplier here is my Controler code..

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SuppliersList = db.Suppliers.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        //{
        //    Value = c.Name,
        //    Text = c.Name

        //});            

        ViewBag.SupplierList = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "Name", "Name");
        return PartialView("_Create");
    }

    // POST: /Frames/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include="FrameId,Name,FrameCode,FrameFor,Brand,Material,Color,FrameType,FrameShape,Bridge,LensWidth,FrameWidth,TempleLength,LensHeight,FrameWeight,Quantity,PurchaseRate,SaleRate,Supplier,Discription,Status,CreatedOn")] Frame frame)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Frames.Add(frame);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }



        return PartialView("_Create", frame);
    }
```

and my ViewCode

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Supplier)
                    @Html.DropDownList("Supplier", ViewBag.SupplierList as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Supplier)
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ViewBag and `DropDownList` html helper method, you should set the selected item's Name(*sine you used Name as the value property for SelectLis*t) in `ViewBag.Supplier` as that is the value you used for the first parameter of `DropDownList` helper method here.

```
var suppliers = db.Suppliers.ToList();
ViewBag.SupplierList = new SelectList(suppliers , "Name", "Name");
// Here i am setting the 2 item in suppliers as the selected item. 
// You can change it as needed
ViewBag.Supplier = suppliers[1].Name;  
return PartialView("_Create");
```

If you want to show a default "Please select" option along with the dropdown options, you can use this overload of `DropDownList` method.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    string optionLabel,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

So your code will be

```
@Html.DropDownList("Supplier", ViewBag.SupplierList as SelectList, 
                                        "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Another solution is to not use viewbag and use a strongly typed view model and use `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882700/how-do-i-create-a-view-model-for-a-populated-drop-down-list-in-asp-net-mvc-3/9882809#9882809) is an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the optionLabel override.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Supplier", 
                   ViewBag.SupplierList as SelectList, 
                   "Select Supplier", 
                   new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: thank you so much Shyju and JamieD77 i have tried the Jamie Soloution it Works Thanks Again.