# asp.net mvc drop down list from viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am looking to populate a drop down list from a viewmodel which the data comes from a database. Here is the short hand of what my project looks like:

Model

```
public partial class Model1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Model2   - this will be the info to populate the drop down list

```
public partial class Model2
{
   public string typeID { get; set; }

   public string typeValue { get; set; }
}
```

These two models are then connected to a ViewModel.

ViewModel

```
public class viewModel
{
    public Model1 Model1s { get; set; }

    public Model2 Model2s { get; set; }
}
```

I am unable to create a drop down list at this point using the viewmodel. I have combed over about 50 example on this site but i cannot get mine to work. I know the view contains something along the lines of:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MarketingCampaign , new SelectList(Model.MarketingCampaignType, "CampaignTypeTitle", "CampaignTypeId"), new { id = "yourElementIdIfAny", @class = "yourClassNameIfAny" })
```

will be required. I am also trying to directly input the Value and Text into a field in the model so i can easily pull information from that model which is passed back to the controller instead of using this method:

```
ViewBag.DropDownList = dbContext.Model2.ToList();
```

and retrieving that information from passing the form back and using:

```
string value = form["DropDownList"].ToString()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882700/how-do-i-create-a-view-model-for-a-populated-drop-down-list-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 1):

I created example and upload in Github

[Source code](https://github.com/Oday9/MVC-DropDownList)

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //IsName >> Is name DropDownList
        //typeID >> Is data value
        //typeValue >> Is data text
        ViewBag.IsName = new SelectList(_dbContext.Model2.ToList(), "typeID", "typeValue");
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult ByViewModel()
    {
        List<ViewModel> items = _dbContext.Model2.Select(m => new ViewModel()
        {
            typeID = m.typeID,
            typeValue = m.typeValue
        }).ToList();

        //IsName >> Is name DropDownList
        //typeID >> Is data value
        //typeValue >> Is data text
        ViewBag.IsName = new SelectList(items, "typeID", "typeValue");
        return View();
    }
```

> @Html.DropDownList("IsName")